# How can one find intermediate digits of a root of an algebraic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms, numerical-methods

I was wondering whether there is a way to find intermediate digits of an algebraic equation. For example, if I have

$$234x^{\frac{1}{12345}}-24621x^{\frac{1}{3456}}=1$$

And I want to find the $10^9$th decimal digit after the decimal place of a particular solution. (Note that I chose this example simply to demonstrate the lack of a simple closed-form solution, I am not looking for a specific solution to this particular equation.)

I was wondering if there is any time-efficient way to do this or do I have to calculate every digit before the targeted one?

Comment: There is a famous instance of the partial computation of the digits of a number with the BBP formula for $\pi$ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula). If you can express your number as a power series with small rational coefficients and evaluated at $1/10$, you can use the same working principle.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think continued fractions might be more appropriate, given his equation and their good approximation properties.

Comment: @johnmangual: how do you evaluate a continued fraction without computing the digits from the beginning ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust that's the beautify of it.  using the equation itself as information we deduce more and more continued fraction digits of our number.  see Enrico Bombieri's [continued fractions and algebraic numbers](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.135.107).  our number is definitely algebric, e.g. let $x = z^{12345 \times 3456}$.

Comment: @johnmangual: is there an algorithm to compute the $n^{th}$ decimal in time linlogarithmic with respect to $n$ by continued fractions ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust As this equation is algebraic **yes** we do.  However, numerically finding roots of algorithms is very difficult.  I believe my solution is closest to [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) which solves $f(x) = 0$ with the recursion:
$$ x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$
these have known convergence issues, and we might try to use something more sophisticated like [Halley's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley%27s_method) or [Jenkins-Traub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins%E2%80%93Traub_algorithm).

Comment: @johnmangual: Roots of algorithms ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust oops! Numerical algorithms for finding roots of polynomials... to high precision can be very difficult.  It's unlikely we can get $10^9$ decimal places even with supercomputer, unless we have special information.  $$ . $$ *Historical note*: These algorithms come from a time when no computers were available.  Halley's algorithm above is named from **Sir Edmund Halley**  with the comet named after him.

Comment: Is there an algorithm to compute roots of polynomials to the $n^{th}$ decimal in linlogarithmic time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular case, I can't say very much, but notice this looks very much like [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) for the greatest common divisor.

$$ \mathrm{gcd}(a,b) = 1 \longleftrightarrow \exists \; x,y \in \mathbb{Z} : ax + by =1$$

We can clear denominators:

$$ \frac{234}{24621} - x^{\frac{1}{3456}- \frac{1}{12345}} = \frac{1}{24621 \times x^{\frac{1}{12345}}}$$

To simplify things let $y = x^{\frac{1}{12345}}$ and notice that $\frac{12345}{3456} \approx 3.5$ then

$$ \frac{1}{105} = y^{2.5} + \frac{1}{24621 \times y}
$$

Then we get an upper and lower bound for $y$:

$$ y < \bigg(\frac{1}{105}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2.5}}< 0.16
\hspace{0.25in}\text{and}\hspace{0.25in}
 y > \frac{105}{24621} = \frac{1}{234} > 0.004$$

Going back to our original equation:

$$ \bigg| \frac{1}{105} - y^{2.5}\bigg| = \frac{1}{24621 \times y} < \frac{1}{24621 \times \frac{1}{234}} = \frac{1}{105}$$

It may be very difficult to get the billion digit of $x$ this way, but we have much more to go on than we started.

---

This style of computation loosely resembles Halley's method for solving equations.  It states if we want to solve $f(x) = 0$

$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{2f(x_n)f'(x_n)}{2[f'(x_n)^2 - f(x_n)f''(x_n)} $$

incorporating idea of Newton's [method of fluxions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_Fluxions)... We can also try to solve just using Newton-Raphson method:

$$ x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

In either case we use our work to start with the value $\boxed{y = \frac{1}{10}}$ (since I changed variables)
and try to iterate either Newton or Halley's procedures.  See [On the geometry of Halley’s method](http://ms.yccd.edu/Data/Sites/1/userfiles/facstaff/jthoo/cvandpubs/papers/halley.pdf)

---

One of the original motivating examples of Sir Edmund Halley's method was to demonstrate the example of Thomas Fautet de Lagny:

$$  a + \frac{ab}{3a^3 + b} < (a^3 + b)^{1/3} < \frac{a}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{a^2}{4} + \frac{b}{3a}} $$

As long as $b \ll a^3$.  This tells us for example that $3 + \frac{3}{82} < \sqrt[3]{28} < \frac{3}{2} + \sqrt{ \frac{9}{4} + \frac{1}{9}}$ which is decent.