# upper and lower bounds related to $\sqrt[3]{a^3 + b}$ with $b \ll a$

Tags: inequality, arithmetic, radicals

We can use Taylor series to approximate $a + \frac{b}{3a}\approx \sqrt[3]{a^3 + b}$  with $b  \ll a$.

However, what are precise upper and lower bounds for this quantity?

$$ a + \frac{b}{3a^2} < \sqrt[3]{a^3 + b} < a + \frac{b}{3a^2} + \dots$$

I don't know numerical methods, so I don't know how to say how "good" or "close" these approximations are...

I can imagine the accuracy goes are $error \propto b^k $ for some $k$.

---

**EDIT** I repeat I don't know how to make this more precise, so I give two ideas.  Let $|\epsilon| < M$ then what is the smallest $k$ such that

$$1 +\tfrac{1}{3}\epsilon < \sqrt[3]{1 + \epsilon} < 1 + k(M)\epsilon$$

for all "allowable" $\epsilon$ i.e. $|\epsilon| < M$.

Another idea is to look at my [previous response](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106232/how-can-one-find-intermediate-digits-of-a-root-of-an-algebraic-equation) where I find the rather peculiar inequalities:

$$ a + \frac{ab}{3a^3 + b} < (a^3 + b)^{1/3} < \frac{a}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{a^2}{4} + \frac{b}{3a}} $$

Estimates like these are less practical, and come from a time when calculators were not available.

Comment: Part of Taylor's theorem is that if
$$
f(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^\infty \frac{f^{(i)}(0)}{i!}x^i
$$
then for any $n \in \Bbb N$ and $x_0\in \Bbb R$ there exists a $\xi$ between $0$ and $x_0$ such that
$$
f(x_0) = \left(\sum_{i = 0}^n \frac{f^{(i)}(0)}{i!}x^i\right) + \frac{f^{(n)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}
$$
so you just have to look at the next term in your Taylor expansion and find the biggest it can be for input between $0$ and $a$ (assuming you're letting $a$ be your variable in the Taylor expansion).

Comment: How did you use Taylor's theorem to get the above? For very small $a$ the left hand side is large...

Comment: It looks like your assumption is $b\ll a$.

Comment: The derivative with respect to $b$ (with $b=0$) is ${1 \over 3 a^2}$.

Comment: What do you mean by precise bounds? Unless you specify what you mean by $b \ll a$, it is difficult to be precise...

Comment: @copper.hat that's a great question.  I don't know

Comment: For non negative $a,b$ the function is increasing, so the bounds will be given by the smallest and largest 'allowable' value of $a$.